# RxJS concat only emit on complete / the missing RxJS contactJoin

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I've got an array of Observables and I'm trying to do 2 things:

(1) the subscribe block's next function should only be called once, when everything is done, with an array of all results.

(2) the Observables must be fired in sequence, not all at the same time.

Here's my code so far, where (1) is NOT working and (2) is working:

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3];

const obs$ = nums.map((num) => {
  return rxjs.defer(() => {
    // this is an async op, mimicking an HTTP call
    console.log('firing', num);
    return rxjs.from(
      new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(num), 2000))
    );
  });
});

rxjs.concat(...obs$).pipe(
  // do something here?
).subscribe(
  num => { console.log('next', num) },
  err => { console.error('error', err.message) },
  () => { console.log('complete') }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Actual output:

```
at 0 secs ... firing 1
at 2 secs ... next 1
at 2 secs ... firing 2
at 4 secs ... next 2
at 4 secs ... firing 3
at 6 secs ... next 3
at 6 secs ... complete
```

Desired output:

```
at 0 secs ... firing 1
at 2 secs ... firing 2
at 4 secs ... firing 3
at 6 secs ... next [1, 2, 3]
at 6 secs ... complete
```

Note the timings are important here.

Now I know `forkJoin` combines results like this. The problem with `forkJoin` is that `firing 1` `firing 2` and `firing 3` all happen at the same time but I need them to fire sequentially, which is why I am using `concat`.

How can I achieve the desired output whilst preserving the above desired timings for `firing 1` `firing 2` and `firing 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toArray` inside the pipe of `concat` it will execute each one and then call next after all are done!

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3];

const obs$ = nums.map((num) => {
  return rxjs.defer(() => {
    // this is an async op, mimicking an HTTP call
    console.log('firing', num);
    return rxjs.from(
      new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(num), 500))
    );
  });
});

let output = [];
rxjs.concat(...obs$).pipe(
  rxjs.toArray(),
).subscribe(
  num => {
    console.log('next', num)
  },
  err => {
    console.error('error', err.message)
  },
  () => {
    console.log('complete')
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I expressly cover this in my question, this does not work because firing 1, firing 2 and firing 3 all happen at the same time which fails requirement (2) in my question. Thanks for the time answering however.

Comment: @danday74 `toArray` is the best for this requirement!

Comment: @danday74 sorry didn't read requirement properly, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**use `concatMap` and return your API (Promise) then `toArray`**

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3]

const api = (id) => {
  console.log('firing', id);
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(id), 2000));
};

rxjs.from(ids).pipe(
  rxjs.concatMap(api),
  rxjs.toArray()
).subscribe(
  num => { console.log('next', num) },
  err => { console.error('error', err.message) },
  () => { console.log('complete') }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

By the way, if you use `defer`,you can just return `new Promise`

```
const obs$ = nums.map((num) => {
  return rxjs.defer(() => {
    // this is an async op, mimicking an HTTP call
    console.log('firing', num);
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(num), 500));
  });
});
```